# How come setting sys.modules[__name__] erases closure scopes?

Tags: python, closures

The following code simply puts a lambda in a dictionary and selects the lambda given a key passed to a class constructor. The selected lambda is stored as a property.

The catch is that an object of that selection class is then set as the module.

```
import sys
import logging

LAMBDAS = dict(foo=lambda x: logging.info('foo called with %d', x))

class SelectLambda(object):
    def __init__(self, which):
        self.selected_lambda = LAMBDAS[which]

sys.modules[__name__] = SelectLambda('foo')
```

In the Python console, the following commands are run (assuming the above code is in *scope.py*):

```
>>> import scope
>>> scope.selected_lambda(15)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "scope.py", line 8, in <lambda>
    LAMBDAS = dict(foo=lambda x: logging.info('foo called with %d', x), bar=do_bar)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'
```

Obviously `logging.info()` exists normally, and I've confirmed that anything inside the function that would have normally pulled in via the closure scope becomes `None`.

This also occurs if the lambda is substituted with a fully-fledged function reference.

It should be noted that without the final line, the `sys.modules` modification, this isn't an issue.

Putting aside whether or not the last line is bad practice, why does closure information get completely discarded when the module is re-defined in such a way?

Comment: I presume this is python2?

Comment: Works in 3.4, 3.5; does not work in <= 3.2 (didn't have 3.3 to test)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 2.7, yes. Should I tag it as such? This is the first Python-related question I've asked.

Comment: Thanks @AnttiHaapala - This was surprisingly hard to search for.

Comment: @Qix  I still got a slight headache trying to adapt that one to your case :D

Comment: See also the presentation by [David Beazley](http://www.dabeaz.com/modulepackage/ModulePackage.pdf) (there's also a video on youtube) on some alternate takes on this pattern.